# C# Read data from a text file and display in Text areas parallelly

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to develop an application in C# with two screens, each contains 2 text Areas/Boxes in it.

When user presses the Start button on first screen, the application should start reading the text file ( having some data on each line ) and populate the odd lines in one text area and even lines on other text area parallelly.

Also, there will be a separate screen ( with 2 text areas ) where you will send data from first screen via TCP to fill the 2 text areas based upon the odd/even line #.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
textbox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Comment: Hi Selva, this solution is not working for me.Also, there will be a separate screen ( with 2 text areas ) where you will send data from first screen via TCP to fill the 2 text areas based upon the odd/even line #.